# SQL Server - collation - difference between Latin1_General_CI_AS and Latin1_General_CS_AS

Tags: sql-server, collation

How can I see the difference between

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES ('A'),('B'),('Y'),('Z'), ('a'),('b'),('y'),('z')) V(C)
ORDER BY C COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES ('A'),('B'),('Y'),('Z'), ('a'),('b'),('y'),('z')) V(C)
ORDER BY C COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

?. For this set of characters there is no difference.

Cheers
Bartosz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an integer ID column to your set of values, and order by that after ordering by C.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES  (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'y'),(4,'z'),(5,'A'),(6,'B'),(7,'Y'),(8,'Z'),(9,'a'),(10,'b'),(11,'y'),(12,'z')) V(ID,C)
ORDER BY C COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,ID

SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'y'),(4,'z'),(5,'A'),(6,'B'),(7,'Y'),(8,'Z'),(9,'a'),(10,'b'),(11,'y'),(12,'z')) V(ID,C)
ORDER BY C COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,ID
```

For the first table, which is case sesitive, 'a' <> 'A', so they are treated seperately. Our ordering puts lowercase a first, and then orders them by ID (1, 9), and then follows with uppercase A.

```
ID  C
1   a
9   a
5   A
```

In the second table, 'a'='A', so they are treated in the same group, and the 3 a (or A) values are ordered together on ID number

```
ID  C
1   a
5   A
9   a
```

And this pattern continues for b, y and z.

Comment: Thank you. If it would be binary sorting then I would have ABCabc. What collation should I use if I would like to have AaBaCa?

Comment: If you use `ORDER BY C COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, C COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS desc`, it will sort each letter group into order first without case, and then sort with case, but putting the upper case first (`desc`).

Comment: Thank you BeanFrog

Comment: There is also a mistake in the title of this question. How can I change it?

Comment: There is an edit link at the bottom of the question - it should be in pale grey and be just under the tags.